# Disallow JavaScript to POST to an URL

Tags: javascript, xss

I am currently having issues with Cross Site Scripting (XSS) weaknesses in a web app. Therefore I wonder if there's something like `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors` and `X-Frame-Options` for JavaScript?

My goal is to disallow the (good user's) browser from doing a POST to a specific URL via JavaScript (e.g. using `XMLHttpRequest`), while the "traditional" POST from the HTML form should be allowed. The idea is to prevent a malicious JavaScript from sending a POST request into the web app without user interaction.

It is similar to frame hijacking: By sending the `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors` header with a URL, I can tell the browser not to put this URL into a frame. Now, I would like to tell the browser not to load a URL via JavaScript. Is there any such option?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to accomplish this... the browser (and the server) can't tell what was loaded "via JavaScript" vs "via HTML" -- and it wouldn't matter anyways, because XSS could simply create an HTML form and submit that automatically.

Your best bet might be to use some sort of anti-CSRF token that loads as part of the server-rendered HTML form. Not 100% foolproof for your use-case, but would do the trick.

Comment: Okay ... creating a form and then submitting it is a quite convincing argument. Thanks!